# Does a Visa/MasterCard issued by a non-Russian bank work via Samsung Pay in Russia?

Tags: russia, payment-cards, payment

The [official website](https://www.samsung.com/ru/mobile/samsungpay/) says that Samsung Pay continues to work in Russia with a few restrictions, one of which being the inability to add a Visa/MasterCard issued by Russian banks. Nothing is said about cards issued by foreign banks. I asked Samsung customer service in a chat as to whether the combination of a foreign credit card and Samsung Pay works in Russia, and they said that if the card was issued in the same country for which the phone was produced, then that combination will "most likely" work. But I'd like to get a more accurate answer than "most likely yes"... Does anyone know for sure whether such a combination (Samsung Pay + Visa/MasterCard issued by a non-Russian bank) works in Russia?

Comment: "Don't allow money from US entities (includes Mastercard/Visa) to flow into Russia" That is the point of sanctions, I think. I will be surprised if this works.

Comment: I think this should mostly be equivalent to “can I use a foreign credit card in Russia?”. At the very least, if the latter is not possible, I don’t quite see how it would be possible using Samsung Pay (which is, AFAIK, just a way to include a credit card in a phone).

Comment: And the answer to that seems to be “no”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Country of device (=Region code) doesn't matter.
Samsung Pay itself will work with non-Russian VISA/MC cards but terminals will refuse such transactions.
Yes, I tested this.

There is one exception: fully offline payments like public transit - they attempt to charge card later, fail to do so and sometimes ban card until this is clarified (this also happens with Russian-bank issued Mir cards if they don't have funds,etc).

Answer (score 3):

From personal experience, Apple Pay and foreign Mastercard/VISA credit cards don't work in Russia currently.

The same is probably true for Samsung Pay. You'd either need a Russian bank card/account or cash.

*(Curiously enough, Moscow metro turnstiles  recognize Apple Pay payments as valid, but seem to not charge anything.)*

Comment: Thanks, but frankly speaking, I don't see how this answer is better than Samsung customer service's "most likely yes". It's not surprising that Apple Pay doesn't work in Russia since it officially ceased operation (which isn't true of Samsung Pay).

Comment: @user557 when you make a payment with a card added to Samsung Pay, does it appear on the card’s statement like if you had used the card directly (I.e. with the name of the merchant, not Samsung as the merchant)? If so the app just carried an emulation of the original card, and the payment needs to be processed by Visa or MasterCard, and those no longer process any transactions in Russia). It may have been different if you had a UnionPay card.

Comment: @user557 Fair enough; what I tried to say is that non-Russian cards don't work in principle - including the physical card itself. I am not sure if Samsung Pay works differently on the backend than Apple Pay (related to jcaron's comment), but the end result (that payments through non-Russian cards don't process) would remain the same. So the answer is rather "most likely no".